# Custom Field Suite A little problem

Tags: custom-field

I have simple coding problem and I'm hoping someone to help me out.

I have created a custom filed with CFS and I called it tracking_url
It holds a URL value eg. google.com/?tracking123423423....

Filed type I set to: hyperlink in the back-end of wordpress.

On the front-end I want to create a button with href the value of tracking_url
I wrote this code but for reason the code is breaking. (not working as I expect to)

```
<button class="claim-button"> <a href="<?php echo CFS()->get( 'tracking_url' ); ?>">Claim Bonus</a> </button>
```

Maybe it because CFS is returning a hyperlink instead of text. I dont know. Any ideas how to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

either change the field type to text and echo it out as you currently are or remove the  tag and echo out the link as is:

```
<button class="claim-button"><?php echo CFS()->get( 'tracking_url' ); ?></button>
```

http://customfieldsuite.com/field-types/hyperlink.html

OR (and this would be my choice if I was you)  Switch to ACF and use that for all your custom fields.  in which case you would probably do this:

```
<button class="claim-button"> <a href="<?php echo get_field('tracking_url'); ?>">Claim Bonus</a> </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation about [hyperlink](http://customfieldsuite.com/field-types/hyperlink.html) field. The hyperlink field is saved as an [associative array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp).
Your hyperlink field will return an associative array look like this

```
/*
    Returns:
    array(
        'url' => 'http://google.com',
        'text' => 'Visit Google',
        'target' => '_blank'
    )
*/
```

There are **'key'=> 'value'** pairs in the above array. eg:- **url** is the key and **http://google.com** is the value. **text** is the key and **Visit Google** is the value, etc. So you need to echo your hyperlink using the key **'url'**. First you need to assign your hyperlink array to a variable. As you can see here I have assigned it to a variable called **$link**. Then echo the value of the url key using **echo $link['url'];**

First try to understand how [associative array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) works, then try the following  code.

```
$link = CFS()->get( 'tracking_url');
<button class="claim-button"><?php echo $link['url']; ?></button>
```